# Buttons in jQuery Mobile popup shift/jump when tapped

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

In my PhoneGap compiled jQuery Mobile apps I've experienced a weird display error with popups. When you tap on a button inside of a popup (or sometimes just when it comes up) the buttons inside shift down and to the right causing an ugly formatting problem like the below:

[image: An example of what happened when "Cancel" was pressed]

To make it more confusing, it's not consistent. Sometimes it happens and sometimes not with no detectable pattern. Also, I've never seen it on a regular computer browser but it consistently does it in an Android PhoneGap app. I've also experienced it with multiple versions of jQM and PhoneGap. Does anyone have any ideas what causes this/how to fix it?

Here is the code for the above popup for the sake of completeness:

```
<a href="#reallyFinishGame" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop" data-transition="none" data-role="button" data-position-to="window" id="tabButton">

<div data-role="popup" id="reallyFinishGame" class="ui-content">
    <h2>Finish this game?</h2>
    <p>You can still edit it later from the "View" section.</p>
    <a href="" data-role="button" onClick="finishGame()" data-theme="a">Yes, go ahead</a>       
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>    
</div>
```

Comment: is page div the direct parent of popup div?

Comment: Oh, no it isn't - I'll try that and let you know if it resolves the problem.

Comment: @Omar: I just tried it and it still has the same problem.

Comment: @DavidDaudelin I am having the same problem now, did you ever correct this?

Comment: No, never figured it out.